# Did the "I" in the debug screen get removed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There was a letter "I" in the debug screen before 1.9.

Wiki did not say that "I" got removed.

Is it still there?

Comment: Can you not start Minecraft? I don't really see the reason for this question. Why would you assume that it got removed?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the I(invisible entity) data did indeed get removed from the f3 screen in Minecraft 1.9 and upwards.

Comment: tysm! :D i was wondering where the update thing was